# i want to view the profile(details) of a specific logged customer from sql database to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

here is my viewprofile.aspx code where the binding will take place. im planning to bind my data in sql to my gridview but it is showing me all of the data(from sql) instead of that of the specific logged in customer. Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["New"] != null)
            {
                bindgrid();
            }
        }
public void bindgrid()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UserData WHERE Username = Username ", conn);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("", conn);
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from UserData WHERE Username = Username", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "data");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> it is showing me all of the data(from sql) instead of that of the
>   specific logged in customer

That's because of the `WHERE` condition in your `SELECT` query which says `WHERE Username = Username` which is a `TAUTOLOGY` and will always be `TRUE` and so fetching all rows.

In essence your `SELECT` query is just doing

```
select * from UserData;
```

You need to specify the logged in customerid in `WHERE` condition to get his/her record.

Considering that you have a variable named `Username` in your `ASP.NET` code where you have stored current logged in customer name; then change your code like below

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UserData WHERE Username = @Username ", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
```

Comment: thank you for the fast response. can you guide me on how can i store the logged in customer?

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod, I am not sure what kind of authentication you have used in your ASP.NET application but try getting httpcontext currentuser like `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` which would give you the logged user name.

Comment: SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True");
            conn.Open();
            string checkuser = "select count(*) from UserData where Username = '" + txtUser.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(scm.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            conn.Close();

Comment: i have this code in my log in button. does this make sense?

Comment: can you give me a sample of that kind of code that you have given me? much appreciated sir

Comment: Yes your code make sense but make sure to use parametrized query as shown in answer. Check MSDN for more information.

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@Username". i have this error when i try to click on the view profile button..

Comment: You need to define it as shown in answer `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUser.Text);`. Read here more https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod, consider accepting the answer if it helped by clicking the check button. Pointing it since you are a new user.

Comment: i do have that kind of code. but it is in my registration.aspx page. => string insertQuery = "insert into UserData(Username,Firstname,Lastname,Email,Password,CustomerType,DeliveryAddress,Zip,ContactNumber)values(@Username,@Firstname,@Lastname,@Email,@Password,@CustomerType,@DeliveryAddress,@Zip,@ContactNumber)";
                SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
                scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUser.Text);